# Android Application Saving/Loading In Internal Storage In Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, persistence

I am working on a simple note taking app to learn android but I got stuck at saving/loading in internal store in fragment. The fragment is basically a list view with array adapter.  When I type something in EditText and click the button then it addes these notes to the list. And when I longclick on one of those notes then it removes that note from the list. Without saving/loading methods the app is working fine but when I add save/load methods then I am having problems, so I know there is problem with my code with internal storage.

The Problem: I have loading file method in onCreate() method and saving file method in both onClick and onItemLongClick. When I start the app, it loads from the file with no problem. When I add a note then it adds that note to the list with no problem. And when I longclick on a note after adding a note then it removes that note with no problem. BUT if I try to longclick on a note before adding a note then app crashes. Or if I go to another fragment in the app and then come back to the main fragment and try to longclick on a note then app crashes again.

My Question: Could you please advise a way to fix the issue and help me to save/load data to internal storage?

You can find the fragment codes below:

**MainProjectLister.java:**

```
public class MainProjectLister extends ListFragment implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    Button addProjectButton;
    EditText addProjectEditText;
    public String projectTitle;
    Projekt newProjekt;
    ProjektSingleton projektSingleton;
    ArrayList<Projekt> projektArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<Projekt> tempProjektArrayList;

    ArrayList<String> ListOfP;

    private final String FILENAME="testfile13.txt";
    private final String FILENAME2="testfile14.txt";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListOfP = new ArrayList<String>();
        projektSingleton = ProjektSingleton.getInstance();
        projektSingleton.setProjektList(getSavedArrayList());
        ListOfP = getSavedStringList();

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_project_lister_layout, container, false);

        addProjectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addProjectButton);
        addProjectEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addProjectEditText);

//addProjectButton onClck method

        addProjectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

//Checking if nothing is entered in the EditText and gives Error messaga
               if(TextUtils.isEmpty(addProjectEditText.getText().toString().trim())){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please type details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                projectTitle = addProjectEditText.getText().toString();
                newProjekt = new Projekt(projectTitle);
                projektArrayList = projektSingleton.getProjectList();
                projektArrayList.add(newProjekt);

                ListOfP.add(projectTitle);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                saveArrayList(projektArrayList);
                saveStringList(ListOfP);

            }

        });

        getActivity().setTitle("Notes");

        return view;
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListOfP);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

        MainProjectLister frag = new MainProjectLister();
        ProjectListFragmentChanger fragInterface = (ProjectListFragmentChanger) getActivity();
        fragInterface.projectListChangeFragment(frag);

        projektSingleton.setProjectNumber(i);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

        projektArrayList.remove(i);
        ListOfP.remove(i);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        saveArrayList(projektArrayList);
        saveStringList(ListOfP);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LongClick works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }


    //Interface

    public interface ProjectListFragmentChanger{

        public void projectListChangeFragment(Fragment fragment);

    }

//Save File Method
    public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<Projekt> arrayList) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(arrayList);
            out.close();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    public void saveStringList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(arrayList);
            out.close();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2 x Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }


//Load Text File Method

    public ArrayList<Projekt> getSavedArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Projekt> savedArrayList = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            savedArrayList = (ArrayList<Projekt>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        return savedArrayList;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSavedStringList() {
        ArrayList<String> savedArrayList = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME2);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            savedArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2 x Loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        return savedArrayList;

    }

}
```

**Singleton Class:**

```
public class ProjektSingleton {
    private static ProjektSingleton ourInstance = new ProjektSingleton();

    private ArrayList<Projekt> mProjektList;

    private int mProjectNumber;

    public static ProjektSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private ProjektSingleton() {
        mProjektList = new ArrayList<Projekt>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Projekt> getProjectList(){
        return mProjektList;
    }

    public void setProjektList(ArrayList<Projekt> ProjektList) {
        this.mProjektList = ProjektList;
    }

    public int getProjectNumber() {
        return mProjectNumber;
    }

    public void setProjectNumber(int projectNumber) {
        this.mProjectNumber = projectNumber;
    }
}
```

**Error:** This is the error I get when I try to longclick on an item in the list to remove it as soon as the application starts. Same error occurs when I click and go to another fragment then come back to MainProjectLister fragment and tries to longclick and remove the item. But it works without error if I remove load methods from the code. And I don't get error when I first add an item on the list then longclick and remove items.:

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lenovo.projectlist, PID: 2386
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
                      at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
                      at com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainProjectLister.onItemLongClick(MainProjectLister.java:133)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3236)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3153)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**This is the line 133:** It is my singleton which I store the ArrayList. If I remove that line or if I remove load methods then there is no error.

```
projektArrayList.remove(i);
```

Comment: Add the exception trace you get, to your question.

Comment: Hi @MehdiB. I have added the error message in my question, when I longclick on an item in the listview I get this error. I'd appreciate if you could advise a solution.

Comment: could you please run the code updated above and paste the exact and entire exception you get on the logs? And also please point out what's the line 130 and 133 in the code.

Comment: Hi @MehdiB. I have put my whole MainProjectLister.java code, line 133, singleton class and whole error message in the question. It would be great help if you could find time to have a look and see what to do to fix the problem.

Comment: it's because you don't fill the `projektArrayList` with data prior to the long click event. The only time you fill it with data is on `onClick` event.

Comment: I have initialize `projektArrayList` inside `onItemLongClick()` method and now it works like a charm. Thank you for the help! @MehdiB.